# parametrize curve rotating about a line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm thinking of parametrizing a surface of revolution created by rotating $y=x^3, 0<x<1$ about the line x = 1. My attempt is let $z=x^3$ and $|x-1|$ be the radius of circle generated by intersection of any plane parallel to $xy$-plane.

So I get a parametrization $\mathbf{x}(u,v) = ((u-1)\cos v, (u-1)\sin v, (u-1)^3\cos ^3 v)$, which does not seem to be right.

Can anyone tell me where did I get wrong?

Comment: I can't undertand what you're trying to do. Try to explain more clearly what you are attempting and check your notation, please.

Comment: After having read your mysteriously worded question, I think you mean that you'd like to parameterize the surface obtained by rotating the line $y = x^3$ graphed from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$ about the line $y = x$.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It is the surface of revolution created by rotating $y=x^3$ about the line $x=1$. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a valid parameterization of what you want:
$$
\mathbf x(u,v) = u(1,0,0) + (1 - u^3)\left(\cos(v)(0,1,0) + \sin(v)(0,0,1)\right)\\
=(u,(1-u^3)\cos(v),(1 - u^3)\sin(v))
$$
Where $u \in [0,1],v\in[0,2\pi]$

Comment: Thanks! This parametrization gives the correct trumpet bell shaped surface. However I'm still wondering if I would like to rotate the curve about the line $y=1$, is it just switching the $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ in your answer?

Comment: Well, then you'd be rotating the curve $x = y^3$ about the line $y = 1$.